# ignore extra occurrences of user input variable for partial matching between user input and reference array

Tags: javascript

Here is a code to compare two sentences word by word and return the number of words **partial matches**.

The code works as expected in case of word partial matching but there is an issue that I can't fix without a hand:

I want to evaluate the user's ability to provide the desired words based on `expectSt`. ( How many expected words user could provide )

The sentences are like this, first one is user input and the second one is the reference to compare the user's input with:

```
// variables of user input (speechResult) and the reference to compare (expectSt)
let speechResult = 'introducing introducing introduced';
let expectSt = 'introduced';
```

As you see we have one occurrence of the word `'introduced'` in the `expectSt` but user input(`speechResult`) has three matching occurrences. The expected result here is to return **one matching** occurrence of course. (`'introduced'` and `'introducing'`  always return a match)

Now, what if we have this:

```
let speechResult = 'introducing introducing introducing ';
let expectSt = 'introducing introducing';
```

This time we should return 2 matches.

The expected matches would be 2 matches because the user was able to guess/provide there are two `introducing` words in the expected. But my code returns one!

That's because all my calculations are based on these lines that removes duplicates:

```
 let uniqA = [...new Set(arrA)]; // remove duplicates
 let uniqB = [...new Set(arrB)]; // remove duplicates
 return Math.min(uniqA.length, uniqB.length);
```

Anyway Here is the full code:

```js
// variables of user input (speechResult) and the reference to compare (expectSt)
let speechResult = 'introducing introducing introduced';
let expectSt = 'introduced';

// Create arrays of words from speechResult and expectSt
let speechResultWords = speechResult.split(/\s+/);
let expectStWords = expectSt.split(/\s+/);

// Initiate the function
let includedWords = includeWords(speechResultWords, expectStWords);

// Here is the result
console.log(includedWords)


// Function to see how many words are in speechResult and expectSt similar
function includeWords(speech, expect){

    let arrA = []; // array to hold simillar words of speechResult 
    let arrB = []; // array to hold simillar words of expectSt 

    for(let a = 0; a < speech.length; a++){
            
        for(let b = 0; b < expect.length; b++){
              /* Check each word of 'speechResult' and 'expectSt' word by word and 
               if there is more than 69 percent simillarity based on levenshtein algorithm accept them as equal words*/
            if(similarity(speech[a], expect[b]) > 69){
               arrA.push(speech[a]);
               arrB.push(expect[b]);          
               console.log(speech[a] + ' includes in ' + expect[b]);
            }
                  
        }  // End of first for loop  
        
    } // End of second for loop
        let uniqA = [...new Set(arrA)]; // remove duplicates
        let uniqB = [...new Set(arrB)]; // remove duplicates
        return Math.min(uniqA.length, uniqB.length); // This line is not what I want and needs some modifucation perhaps..
};


// Levenshtein algorithm as the string metric We Have Nothing To Do With This Part
function similarity(s1, s2) {
        var longer = s1;
        var shorter = s2;
        if (s1.length < s2.length) {
            longer = s2;
            shorter = s1;
        }
        var longerLength = longer.length;
        if (longerLength == 0) {
            return 1.0;
        }
        return (longerLength - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / parseFloat(longerLength)*100;
}

function editDistance(s1, s2) {
        s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
        s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

        var costs = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i <= s1.length; i++) {
            var lastValue = i;
            for (var j = 0; j <= s2.length; j++) {
                if (i == 0)
                    costs[j] = j;
                else {
                    if (j > 0) {
                        var newValue = costs[j - 1];
                        if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
                            newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue),
                                costs[j]) + 1;
                        costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
                        lastValue = newValue;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (i > 0)
                costs[s2.length] = lastValue;
        }
        return costs[s2.length];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I correctly understood what you need, I would recommend to replace your includeWords function to this one:

```
function includeWords(speech, expect){

    let arrA = []; // array to hold expected words found in user speech 

    arrA = expect.filter(item => {
      return speech.some(speechItem => similarity(item, speechItem) > 69)
    });

    return arrA.length
};
```

on your test data from example it returns 2. Please test on another data and tell me if it works as you need :)

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer ... plus one.. I'll test this

Comment: With this date we expect `2` because the user only could guess two of the expected words, instead, we get `3` with your function: `let speechResult = 'introducing introducing'
let expectSt = 'introducing introducing introduce';`

Comment: @SaraRee thanks for the update. In this case I can offer the following: 
first, trim a bit initial strings to avoid empty strings in arrays
`let speechResultWords = speechResult.trim().split(/\s+/);
let expectStWords = expectSt.trim().split(/\s+/);`

and change return statement in my function like this:


`return Math.min(arrA.length, speech.length);`

Comment: God, There is something wired here: This returns one occurrence as expected:  `let speechResult = 'introducing'
let expectSt = 'introducing introducing ';` But this one returns Two! : `let speechResult = 'they introducing'
let expectSt = 'we introducing introducing ';`

Comment: @SaraRee here is the version which works fine on all examples:

`function includeWords(speech, expect){
    let arrA = []; // array to hold simillar words of speechResult 

    let workingSpeech = [...speech];
    expect.forEach(item => {
      const i = workingSpeech.findIndex(speechItem => similarity(item, speechItem) > 69);
      if (i >= 0) {
        arrA.push(item);
        workingSpeech = workingSpeech.filter((wItem, index) => index !== i);
      }
    });

    return arrA.length;
};`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification for my function that worked fine:

```
// Function to see how many words are in user speech and expected similar
function includeWords(speech, expect){

    let similar = []; // array to hold simillar words of expectSt 
    let ignore = [];

    for(let a = 0; a < speech.length; a++){

        for(let b = 0; b < expect.length; b++){
              /* Check each word of 'speechResult' and 'expectSt' word by word and 
               if there is more than 69 percent simillarity based on levenshtein algorithm accept them as equal words*/
               if(!ignore.includes(b)){

                  if(similarity(speech[a], expect[b]) > 69){
                     similar.push(expect[b]); 
                     ignore.push(b);
                     //console.log(speech[a] + ' includes in ' + expect[b]);
                     break;
                   }

               }

        }  // End of first for loop  

    } // End of second for loop

    return similar.length;   

};
```